# How to apply style in data-prototype

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to apply bootstrap in data-prototype but it is not working.

Below is my twig file

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>New Company</h2>
    </div>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="row">
            {{ form_row(form.name) }}
            <h3>Employees</h3>
                <ul class="employees" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.employees.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                    {% for employee in form.employees %}
                        <li>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                {{ form_row(employee.firstName, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                {{ form_row(employee.lastName, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Button type is okay but the employee.firstName and employee.lastName are not.

Comment: Looks ok to me the way you've rendered the firstName and lastName fields, and how you've applied the class attributes. The problem might be somewhere else. What's the error you get?

Comment: no error. I just the output/style is the same with or without the <div class="form-group col-sm-6"> and <div class="form-group col-sm-6">

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have the same styling/layout in the `data-prototype` as you get in the `{% for employee ... %}` loop?

Comment: No, what i mean is that even i added the style nothing happened.

Comment: It's okay now. What I did is to add the class attr in form type instead in twig file.

Comment: $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'color:red')))

Comment: But I'm still wondering why it did not work in twig. They are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dedicated form theme for your collection type.

Example:

<kbd>EmployeeCollectionTypeTheme.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% block EmployeeCollectionType_widget %}
<li>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
         {{ form_row(form.firstName, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
         {{ form_row(form.lastName, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
     </div>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

<kbd>main.html.twig</kbd>

```
{% form_theme form.employees 'AppBundle:Default:EmployeeCollectionTypeTheme.html.twig' %}

<ul class="employees" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.employees.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {{ form_widget(form.employees) }}
</ul>
```

Of course, change form type name to fit with yours (except the `form` variable in the theme, which is given in the prototype context).

To get further, you can check how I built the collection type for templates in https://twigfiddle.com/ (where you have "Add template" in the left pane), by looking at the [theme source code](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Resources/views/Fiddle/templates-theme.html.twig).